# checking if word exist in english dictionary r

Tags: r, shiny, text-mining

I'm performing some text analysis on  mutliple **resume** to generate a `wordcloud` using `wordcloud` package along with `tm` package for preprocessing the corpus of document in R.

The problems i'm facing are :

1. Checking whether the word in corpus have some meaning ie. it belongs to english dictionary.
2. How to mine / process multiple resumes together.
3. Checking for **tech** terms like r,java,eclipse etc.

Appreciate the help.

Comment: have you tried using a custome `dictionary` and checking words from it like tech terms in resume

Comment: @ParthChaudhary, custom `dictionary` is good for `tech` terms but not fruitful for checking english words

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've faced some issues before, so sharing solutions to your problems :

**1.** There is a package `qdapDictionaries` which is a collection of dictionaries and word lists for use with the 'qdap' package.

```
library(qdapDictionaries)

#create custom function
is.word  <- function(x) x %in% GradyAugmented # or use any dataset from package

#use this function to filter words, df = dataframe from corpus
df <- df[which(is.word(df$terms)),]
```

**2.** Using `VCorpus(DirSource(...))` to create your corpus from directory containing all resumes

```
resumeDir <- "path/all_resumes/"
myCorpus <- VCorpus(DirSource(resumeDir))
```

**3.** Create your custom dictionary file like **my_dict.csv** containing `tech` terms.

```
#read custom dictionary
tech_dict <- read.csv("path/to/my_dict.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
#create tech function
is.tech <- function(x) x %in% tech_dict
#filter
tech_df <- df[which(is.tech(df$terms)),]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: what if `tech` words are more and `is.word` takes a lot of time in computation ?

Comment: could try using `lapply` etc. grouping functions to improve performance.

Comment: Hi all, I have a question related to the discussion. I have a list of cities and villages names (about 8000 total). In the list cities may have names of English/American origin, say "Johnsonville" o"Washington", and others completely different names, say "Lagos". Is there a way to detect which are the ones with an English/American name and which are the ones with a name different from English/American?

Answer (score 1):

Try the [`dictionary` R package](https://github.com/stevecondylios/dictionary#dictionary-) (*disclaimer*: I am the maintainer of this R library)

#### Example

Here we get the definition of the word "hello"

```
word <- "hello"
word_info <- define(word)

word_info$meanings
## [[1]]
##   partOfSpeech
## 1  exclamation
## 2         noun
## 3         verb
##                                                                                definitions
## 1                used as a greeting or to begin a phone conversation., hello there, Katie!
## 2 an utterance of ‘hello’; a greeting., she was getting polite nods and hellos from people
## 3                            say or shout ‘hello’., I pressed the phone button and helloed
```

Comment: @tjebo thank you. It’s no coincidence, I put it together for something I was working on this afternoon. I will edit the answer now

Comment: @tjebo yep, 4h 50m (yeah, I timed it, pretty sad huh…)

Comment: No, it's impressive!!

Answer (score 0):

You can also add new words or merge two dictionaries in the following manner:

```
library(qdapDictionaries)

#create custom function
is.word  <- function(x) x %in% c(GradyAugmented, Dictionary2, "new_word1", "new_word2")
```